# Choosing to use QGIS LTR or another version/release type

Tags: qgis

I am after some advice with respect to the QGIS LTR schedule.
Our IT managers have recently intervened in our use of QGIS (a State Government Authority) and are wanting to put in place a policy to only install and use the LTR release version, stating that the other releases are effectively 'Beta' versions.

Their view is from a stability and security standpoint, not from training and process mapping (as that has nothing to do with them).

I have seen and read this article - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/blob/master/QEP-4-QGIS_Long_Term_Releases.rst

Obviously the LTR has a slightly longer testing window so is less likely to have any major issues, but is their view that the other releases are 'Beta' version accurate or misled?

Answer (score 17):

I would say (not being a developer for QGIS) that the only release to be considered beta would be the master builds of QGIS (ie, nightly).

QGIS (long-term release) can be considered static (no new features added) but with cherry-picked patches that are back ported for stability, enhancement and security.

QGIS (current release) is mainly different from the LTR, that in addition to back-ported patches, it'll get new features added (from master version) when they are considered stable enough with frequent releases (proposed every 3 months).

QGIS (master) is the development version of QGIS which I'd say is beta because when you build it daily there are new features that may be incomplete or existing features may become broken. Not intended for production use.

QGIS LTR and QGIS Current Release can be used for production use.

So to decide, it really depends on whether or not it's a priority that you're looking to:

- maintain a GIS with minimal changes and stability through consistency
  (ie, long-term release)
- explore and integrate new functionality from QGIS into your workflows (long-term release, master)
- preparing developed applications and plugins for backwards and future compatibility (long-term + current release, master)
- testing new features (master)
- other...

But to answer your question around security... That's tricky because besides QGIS with it's own many potential use-cases and vulnerabilities there's also a long-tail of dependencies that have to be considered as well. For example, one might be in certain scenarios where the versions of QGIS they're using have a dependency mixup like qt4 or 5, python2 or 3, GRASS 6 or 7, etc that would also have to be taken into consideration for security.

Depending on the operating system, package updates for both the long-term and current release may not be frequent enough to give the patches they fix justice (remember it's volunteer based). I've been able to make use of the development cycle by compiling QGIS on Linux directly from the specific master and release branches off of GIT as needed.

Comment: Very well explained, very succinct and to the point.

Answer (score 2):

My experience as a user and developer of GPL software made me expect something and left me surprised with what I found. So I had to adapt expectations to observations, at least as far as 2.14 and 2.18 are concerned.

I had expected:

- nightly build useful for experimenting new features, and before reporting bugs.
- normal releases for normal use
- LTR release for security and conservative IT Managers

I have been running 2.14 for a couple of months, I'm a sporadic user, and I was surprised to see it misbehave on input fields, while I was quite happy with its overall performance.

I then installed 2.18, I expected the misbehaviour on input fields to have been corrected (it has—as far as I could test), but I was very unpleasantly surprised to see it crash constantly, edit a feature, select an other one, and there it goes. Given such instability, I would not even know where to start to file a bug report.

I don't know if it's just my system, or just 2.18, but my conclusion is that your IT managers are being very wise and that QGIS-ltr is the only acceptable way to use QGIS.

If you have the chance to run two versions next to each other (I still have to see how, on Debian), do that, and be prepared to file bug reports. As for myself, I'm looking forward to the next LTR version.

Comment: You can run two versions of QGIS on the same machine using the OSGEO4W installer.