# QGIS compatibility with Mac OS 10.8.5

Tags: qgis, style, mac, compatibility

I am stuck working with QGIS on an older iMac running OS 10.8.5. I've installed QGIS 2.18.14 and it generally works very well, but I'm running into some issues that get in the way of my work flow. I wonder if I should install an older version of QGIS to get the functionality I need on the older OS... specifically, I am finding that:

1. Styling layers works strangely - as per this thread from a couple of years ago: [QGIS just installed on MAC OSX - vector layer styles do not work properly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157471/qgis-just-installed-on-mac-osx-vector-layer-styles-do-not-work-properly)
2. Exporting the Atlas as images does not give me the option to choose a file format, as per this 2-year-old discussion - https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12435. It lets me choose the directory to save to, but always uses JPEG. I would prefer to export to PNG to get uncompressed output. My back-up is to export PDFs and convert PNG using other software, but I would rather just use a version of QGIS that worked...

If I should install an older version of QGIS, what version should I choose? 2.8 seemed to help some people with the first issue - but that's quite a few versions back now. Maybe something more recent could work? Trial and error?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS 2.18.14 should work from OS X 10.8 and above.

If you want to go back a few versions. I recommend you an [LTR (long term release)](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/blob/master/QEP-4-QGIS_Long_Term_Releases.rst) rather than other ones, because of they [are more stable](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160347/qgis-ltr-vs-other-release).

In this terms, you have the latest two LTR versions to choose, 2.8 and 2.14, specifically 2.8.9 and 2.14.8. The first one could be more suitable to your iMac, because is for older OS X versions (10.7-10.10).

You can download these versions (and more) from [KyngChaos site](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive).

Don't forget to install the necessary dependencies for each one.