# Is it better to use QGIS LTR or current release version

Tags: qgis

When downloading QGIS you can download the Current Release or the LTR Version. But what are the main differences between them? [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160347/qgis-ltr-vs-other-release) this question has been asked before but I don't really understand the answers. In the most voted answer the user wrote:

> QGIS (long-term release) can be considered static (no new features added) but with cherry-picked patches that are back ported for
> stability, enhancement and security.
>
> QGIS (current release) is mainly different from the LTR, that in
> addition to back-ported patches, it'll get new features added (from
> master version) when they are considered stable enough with frequent
> releases (proposed every 3 months).

I understand that the Current Release has the advantage that it has more tools and features, but what are exactly the advantages of the LTR Version? Does it have *better* "back-ported patches"? What are back-ported patches practically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference is that LTR is optimized for stability instead of new features - it's a version that is maintained at least one year. The current releases appear every four months and are maintained thus for a shorter period, but they have new features that the LTR does not have.

Take a look at previous versions: 2.18 (LTR), 3.0, 3.2, 3.4 (LTR), 3.6, 3.8, 3.10 (LTR), 3.12, 3.14, 3.16 (LTR). Every 4 months, a new version is released an is maintained four monts long until the next (newer) version is published. But every third version turns to a LTR after the first 4 monts of it's existence as a "normal version".

For the next year, no new functionalities are added, just improvements for stability (like eliminating critical bugs). In the same time, the release of new versions is going on in the normal rhythm with new features. But the introduction of new features can cause unexpected issues, it also means that improvements in functionality can be a source of new bugs.

So if you are in a productive environment and don't want to change every few months your installation, stick to the LTR. It gives you more stability. If you are looking for the last improvements, check out the newest versions. You can always consult the visual changelog to see what's new: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelogs.html

However, you can have several versions installed and switch between them. At least under Windows, I never had any issues with that.

If you are an occasional user, I would recomend to use the newest version and use the LTR as a fallback if you encounter problems. Probably this is the best recommandation for all who are unsure what to install: always get the newest version.
If you are a professional and for you an unchanged environment is critical for your work, you'd probably prefer LTR. But than you know exactely why you'd do that.

About once a month there are point releases, principally bug fix versions. You're free to install every one of them, even though in most cases that should not be necessary. In my experience, QGIS runs quite stable, regardeless of the version installed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailled answer. Now I understand the differences and I'm able to explain them to my colleagues.